# base64 encode HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, web-services, http

I want to `base64` encode an image that is being received as `HttpPostedFileBase` to send it in a json object and I don't know how it can be done...and please tell me how can I decode it back to `HttpPostedFileBase`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tried this and it worked

```
string theFileName = Path.GetFileName(YourFile.FileName);
byte[] thePictureAsBytes = new byte[YourFile.ContentLength];
using (BinaryReader theReader = new BinaryReader(YourFile.InputStream))
{
    thePictureAsBytes = theReader.ReadBytes(YourFile.ContentLength);
}
string thePictureDataAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(thePictureAsBytes);
```

Comment: you don't use the theFileName here

Comment: @SeanKPS theFileName can be used according to your case, here for example I use it as the input for a web-service that will store it in the database

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to convert the HttpPostedFileBase  to Base64String type

```
  public ActionResult ParseCv(HttpPostedFileBase cvFile)
    {            
        byte[] fileInBytes = new byte[cvFile.ContentLength];
        using (BinaryReader theReader = new BinaryReader(cvFile.InputStream))
        {
            fileInBytes = theReader.ReadBytes(cvFile.ContentLength);
        }
        string fileAsString= Convert.ToBase64String(fileInBytes);
        return Content(fileAsString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
byte[] binaryData;
  binaryData = new Byte[product.BrochureFile.InputStream.Length];
  long bytesRead = product.BrochureFile.InputStream.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)product.BrochureFile.InputStream.Length);
  product.BrochureFile.InputStream.Close();
  string base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
```